# IE textarea wrap bug?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, textarea, word-wrap

It seems that IE starting from IE7 to IE10 wraps text in the textarea control incorrectly when using \n (or \r\n - doesn't matter - results are the same). Is this a bug in IE or they treat the html standard differently than other browsers - who is right? I have defined:

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" runat="server" style="width: 190px; height: 390px; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; overflow: scroll" ></textarea>
```

When I try to add long string like "VeryLongStringEndingWithNewLine\n" by using JavaScript code (obj.value += text;) the text is shown in one line with scroll (this is ok) but added with an additional empty line (\r\n) - why?
When I try to add short string like "Short\n" multiple times, again via JavaScript code the text is on the same line (should be on the separate lines because normal wrapping should be applied).
Moreover when I do postback then all \r\n's are replaced with spaces (why?) and then text parsed correctly (assuming if I used spaces instead of crlf normal wraping with space only wraps when does not fit in the area).

When using FF or Chrome same control behaves correctly - long lines are shown without an additional empty next line, short lines are on the different lines, no replacement with spaces when doing postback.

I know I could probably use other options or white space characters, but I feel that above is not correct about IE. Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, textareas treat whitespace literally and wrap as needed.

But because you're overriding it with CSS, the result is potentially unstable.

In this case, whitespace (`\n`) is collapsing to a single space, since that's what `white-space:normal` does.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, since I'm fairly sure the default behaviour for textareas is perfectly fine. If you don't want that behaviour, you shouldn't be using a textarea.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Simply I am trying to add records as rows to the textarea and if it does not fit in one line I want to horizontal scrollbar to appear. I don't want that one record would take more than one line, no matter how long it is. I think if the control supports the documented properties why should I use anything else?

Comment: You might be better off just using a `<div>` for each record.

Comment: I would pass the textarea value later to some other processing so using div's not that convenient

Comment: Ok, default behaviour (I have removed "white-space: normal;") works correctly on IE and FF, but Chrome now behaves similarly like IE before. Because this will not published to Internet, it will work for me, thanks Kolink.